# ePic - what’s the relations with physics?

Tags: algorithm, desktop, physics

What is the relation with Physics and techniques ? I am interested in learning the algorithms followed in this 3d photo viewer [ePic](http://www.epicreal.com).

Any other known physics engine ?

Comment: This questions is badly underspecified and unclear. Once you've fixed that we may be able to see *if* there is a relationship to programming in there.

Answer (score 1):

EPic is software that runs on a computer. Computers use semi-conductors, which rely on quantum physics. That is probably the only relation between ePic and physics.

(actually it looks a bit like [bump-top](http://bumptop.com/), but that's game physics not real physics )

Comment: Thank you. I Would like to learn that for a physical engine the ePic uses (Bullet, ODE) ???